# How to insert form data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I study laravel, waching a youtube. (https://youtu.be/ko4PU4eplnY : watching at 12:48)

However, there is something I don't understand, so I ask you a question.

I make the custom login logic. But How insert data to mysql?

[image]

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        //return $request->input();
        //validate
        $request->validate([
            'user_id'=>'required',
            'user_pass'=>'required|min:4|max:16',
            'user_pass_chk'=>'required|min:4|max:16',
            'email'=>'required|email',
        ]);

        //insert data
        $user = new Users;
        $user->user_id = $request->user_id;
        $user->user_pass = Hash::make($request->user_pass);        
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $register = $user->register();

        if($register){
            return back()->with('success', 'insert success');
        }else{
            return back()->with('fail', 'insert failed');
        }

    }
}



class Users extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no function `register` on the user model. `save()` is what saves the data, as shown at that point of the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     //insert data
    $user = new Users;
    $user->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $user->user_pass = Hash::make($request->user_pass);        
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user-≥save();
```

But make sure you have that filed in data table like right now no user_id exist in your table etc....And at last no need to use user class, it's already use/imported at top.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `register()` on the users model that's why error `Bad method call`

You can use save() function instead.

```
$register = $user->save();
```